# Replace regular expression javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string like this

`|1.774|1.78|1|||||1.781|1||||||||`

I applied a replace expression

```
str = str.replace(/\|\|/g, '| |')
```

Output result is

```
|1.774|1.78|1| || ||1.781|1| || || || |
```

but the result must be like

```
|1.774|1.78|1| | | | |1.781|1| | | | | | | |
```

Where is the error?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a lookahead here to check for a `|` after a `|`:

```
str = str.replace(/\|(?=\|)/g, '| ')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3gZyju/1)

**Details**

- `\|` -  a literal `|`
- `(?=\|)` - a positive lookahead that matches but does not consume the next `|` char, thus keeping it outside of the match and this char is still available to be matched during the next iteration.

Comment: That response in 40 seconds tho ^^

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, instead of using a regular expression you can use the following javascript function:

```
let original = '|1.774|1.78|1|||||1.781|1||||||||';

let str = original.split('|').map((e, i, arr) => {
    // 1) if the element is not on the end of the split array...
    // 2) and if element is empty ('')
    // -> there's no data between '|' chars, so convert from empty string to space (' ')
    if (i > 0 && i < arr.length -1 && e === '') return ' ';
    // otherwise return original '|' if there is data found OR if element is on the end
    // -> of the split array
    else return e
}).join('|')
```

Wiktor's regex is quite beautiful, but I just thought I'd offer a plain JS version.